# Passing checkbox value to array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, input, event-binding

I'm working on a solution where each of the inputs, generated depending on the passenger number, gets additional checkboxes. I want to pass the value of each checkbox and bind it to the input next to it. The plan is to eventually end up with an array in which I have the value of the input field + each checkbox value. I am not sure how to move forward with this. For now, I have:

COMPONENT.HTML:

```
<li *ngFor="let passenger of createRange(showStorage.passengersNumber); let i=index"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="passengersData[i]" placeholder="Name and surname">
<input type="checkbox" (click)="addChild($event)">Child
<input type="checkbox" (click)="addLuggage($event)">Luggage
</li>
```

COMPONENT.TS

```
  constructor() {
    this.passengersData = [];
  }

  public passengersData: any[];
  public luggageCounter: number = 0;
  public childrenCounter: number = 0;

  createRange(number){
  var items: number[] = [];
  for(var i = 1; i <= number; i++){
     items.push(i);
  }
  
  return items;
}

  addLuggage(event) {
    console.log("Added luggage");
    this.luggageCounter++
  }

  addChild(event) {
    this.childrenCounter++
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Thanks for any help!

STACKBLITZ: https://stackblitz.com/edit/flight-date-picker-with-service-done-qfmn6p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array with a name property and boolean properties for child and luggage and regenerate the array only when the number of passengers is updated retaining the previous passengers.

Here is a working StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s7dtu4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
Number of passengers <input type="text" [ngModel]="passengers.length" (ngModelChange)="updateNumOfPassengers($event)">
<li *ngFor="let passenger of passengers; let i=index">
  <input type="text" [name]="'name_' + 1" [(ngModel)]="passenger.name" placeholder="Name and surname">
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="passenger.child" (change)="passenger.child = !passenger.child">Child
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="passenger.luggage" (change)="passenger.luggage = ! passenger.luggage">Luggage
</li>
```

```
  passengers = [];

  updateNumOfPassengers(input: string) {
    const numOfPassengers = parseInt(input);
    if (!isNaN(numOfPassengers) && numOfPassengers >= 0) {
      const passengersToAdd = numOfPassengers - this.passengers.length;
      if (passengersToAdd > 0) {
        this.passengers = [...this.passengers, ...Array.from({ length: passengersToAdd }, _ => ({ name: '', child: false, luggage: false }))];
      } else if (passengersToAdd < 0) {
        this.passengers = this.passengers.filter((_, index) => index < numOfPassengers);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for this solution but, maybe I'm doing something wrong - apparently the code crashes the website. I tried this on stackblitz and in visual studio code and it both cases the website stops on infinite loading. I added a missing quotation mark after let i=index. Can you please check again what's the issue here?

Comment: I haven't tested the code, I might try run up a StackBlitz tomorrow, it is way too late on Friday night today.

Comment: Hi, sure, no problem and thank you in advance! :) Regards from CET+2 time zone

Comment: This was never going to work, each time change detection runs the createRange function will create a new array.

Comment: Adrian - one more question -> how should the code look like if there is already a set number of passengers taken from local storage and user cannot change it at this point? I tried editing it this way but I don't know how to do it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `passengers = Array.from({ length: numOfpassengers }, _ => ({ name: '', child: false, luggage: false }));`

Comment: Ok - if I understand correctly, the passengers variable should be assigned to the local storage number value, but it still leaves me with this input field that launches the function and where it asks to put the number of passengers. Instead I'm looking for something that will make those input fields already appear depending on the already set passengers number.

Comment: `passengers = Array.from({ length: parseInt(localStorage['numOfPassengers']) }, _ => ({ name: '', child: false, luggage: false }));` is all you need, no need for the function at all, just declare the passengers array.